# R: Loop in a function to fill a data frame

Tags: r, function, loops, dataframe

I have three weather stations to create a single weather data register and data frames for each variable registered. For example:

HR is the data frame containing the registered relative humidity data for three stations and feed is the data frame where me weighted average should be saved for each variable. In this case, I am only applying the function to relative humidity to fill the second column in feed data frame.

```
HR<-data.frame(M5125=c(70,75,NA,NA),
               M5126=c(73,NA,NA,71.5),
               PRAA=c(NA,NA,NA,NA))

precip<-data.frame(M5125=c(16,NA,11,NA),
               M5126=c(7,NA,NA,13),
               PRAA=c(15,NA,NA,NA))

>HR
 .    M5125      M5126      PRAA
[1,]   70          73        NA
[2,]   75          NA        NA
[3,]   NA          NA        NA
[4,]   NA         71.5       NA


daily<-c('2015-10-11','2015-10-12','2015-10-13','2015-10-14')

feed<-data.frame(daily,HR_percent=NA,precip_mm=NA)
```

I want to fill a single data frame with a weighted average, but there are some NA in different dates for each stations. So I created a function to fill it according the case.

```
WAM<-data.frame(STATIONS=c('M5125','M5126','PRAA'),
                WEIGHT=c(5,2,1.6))

wamFunction<-function(MV,col){
  for (r in 1:nrow(feed)) {
    feed[r,col]<-weighted.mean(MV[r,],WAM[,2],na.rm = T)
  }
}

mapply(wamFunction,HR,2)
mapply(wamFunction,precip,3)
```

The function should return to cells a weighted average depending on availability data in each station

This is the error returned:

> Error in `[.default`(MV, v, 2) : wrong dimensions number

Comment: Both data frame, feed and HR, have the same number of rows

Comment: Could you describe in words what you're doing? I think there might be a much simpler way using the `weighted.mean` function (which has a `na.rm` argument). But I'm confused that your `feed` sample data doesn't seem to have `STATION` info, and I don't get where the `HR` data you show fits in. Any chance you could share a few rows of sample data to make it reproducible?

Comment: `dput()` is an easy way to share a bit of data in a copy/pasteable way, e.g., `dput(feed[1:10, ])` for the first 10 rows of the `feed` data.

Comment: Sure, @GregorThomas. HR is the data frame containing the registered relative humidity data for three stations and feed is the data frame where me weighted average should be saved for each variable.
In this case, I am only applying the function to relative humidity to fill the second column in feed data frame.

Comment: @GregorThomas, I tried using weighted.mean function. It works using only the loop, but it can't be used inside the function. It would be better if i got a function to apply it to each variable's data frame.
wamFunction<-function(MV,col){
  for (r in 1:nrow(feed)) {
    feed[r,col]<-weighted.mean(MV[r,2:4],na.rm = T)
  }
}
mapply(wamFunction,HR,2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a function, with slightly different structure, but serves the purpose:

```
HR<-data.frame(M5125=c(70,75,NA,NA),
               M5126=c(73,NA,NA,71.5),
               PRAA=c(NA,NA,NA,NA))

precip<-data.frame(M5125=c(16,NA,11,NA),
               M5126=c(7,NA,NA,13),
               PRAA=c(15,NA,NA,NA))



# define the function
# df is the dataframe
# wgt is the weights to be used
# if append = TRUE, then a dataframe with the 
# weighted average column will be returned
# if append  = FALSE (default), then an array with 
# wighted avg will be returned

get_wgt_avg = function(df, wgt, append = FALSE){
  if(ncol(df) != length(wgt)){
    stop("number of columns in df and weights' length differ")
  }

  output <- rep(NA, nrow(df))
  for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
    output[i] <- weighted.mean(df[i,], w = wgt, na.rm = TRUE)
  }
  if(append){
    df$wgt_avg = output
    return(df)
  }else{
    return(output)
  }
}


# get weighted avg for the HR data
HR_Wgt_avg <- get_wgt_avg(HR, wgt = c(5, 2, 1.6))
print(HR_Wgt_avg)



# include column in the precip df
precip_2 <- get_wgt_avg(precip, wgt = c(5, 2, 1.6), append = TRUE)
print(precip)
print(precip_2)
```

Answer (score 0):

I agree with the others that it would help to get a sample of the data to check it out. from a first brief glance at your function I would assume that you use `mapply` in an unintended way. Your function addresses locations in the data frame directly. `mapply` , however, will pass only the columns to `wamFunction`.

You can check this doing this:

```
mapply(str, WAM)
```

Hence, an instruction like `MV[v,2]`cannot work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend `melt`ing your dataset into long form, and then you'll find it much easier to filter out NAs etc. without needing to use loops. Here's an example using `data.table`:

```
library(data.table)
setDT(precip)
precip[, day:=daily]  # Add in a "day" column to the data

# Turn the data into long form, and filter out any NAs to leave only valid values
precip.long <- melt(precip, id.vars='day', variable.name='STATIONS', value.name='precip')[!is.na(precip)]

precip.long[WAM, WEIGHT:=i.WEIGHT, on='STATIONS']  # Join the weights in
precip.long[, weighted.mean(precip, WEIGHT), by='day']  # Group by day and apply weighted mean
```